# Reducing memory footprint of ReportViewer

Tags: c#, optimization, .net

We have implemented a process using C# and [`ReportViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer(v=vs.90).aspx) to create PDFs by the [`LocalReport.Render`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252199(v=vs.90).aspx) method. When we have to process a big file, say more than 20000 records, the process fails with an `OutOfMemoryException`. I know there may be lot of causes for this error, but I want to know if the below code is okay or if you can give me a better solution. I have about 40 case statements each calling different `.rdlc` files and it is based on the type; I did not include all the case statements due to lack of space.

`USP_Select_Batch_Address_To_Sort` is a `DataSet` defined in the solution executing a stored procedure accepting three parameters (in this case batch, run and sequence #).

Is this approach feasible? How can it be improved?

```
public static void GenerateIndividualPDFs(string batch, string run, MainDataSet1 DS, MainDataSet1TableAdapters.USP_Select_Batch_Address_To_SortTableAdapter Ta, BindingSource bs, int intStart = 0, int intEnd = 0, string strLetterType = "")
        {
            reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
            reportDataSource.Value = bs;
            int count;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;

            var batchinfo = new clsBatchInfo();

            ReportViewer report = new ReportViewer();

            report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);


            if (!Directory.Exists(mstrFilePath + "\\" + batch + run))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(mstrFilePath + "\\" + batch + run);
            }
            var DA = new clsGetBatchSort();

            //this dataAdapter will print the full set
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(DA.dsBatch_Sort(batch, run));


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            int i = 0;
            int LetterTypeID = 0;

            report.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

  foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                i++;
                report.Clear();
                Ta.ClearBeforeFill = true;
                try
                {


                LetterTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
                switch (LetterTypeID)
                {
                    case 1:                                      
                {

                    Ta.Fill(DS.USP_Select_Batch_Address_To_Sort, Convert.ToDecimal(batch), run,  Convert.ToInt32(dr["MPresortID"]));
                    report.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportsApplication1.ABC.MAENG.rdlc";
                    ExportReport(Convert.ToInt32(dr["MPresortID"]), batch, run, report);
                    continue;
                }
                    case 2:
                {
                     Ta.Fill(DS.USP_Select_Batch_Address_To_Sort, Convert.ToDecimal(batch), run,  Convert.ToInt32(dr["MPresortID"]));
                    report.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportsApplication1.ABC.MASPA.rdlc";
                    ExportReport(Convert.ToInt32(dr["MPresortID"]), batch, run, report);
                    continue;
                }
 catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    clsEmail.EmailMessage("Error Batch " + batch + run, "clsGenerateLetters " + ex.Message);
                    continue;
                    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    //return "";
                }
            }
}

 private static void ExportReport(int PreSortID, string batch, string run, ReportViewer Report)
      {           

          Report.RefreshReport();

          Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string filenameExtension;

            string fmt = "00000000";



            byte[] bytes = Report.LocalReport.Render(
                "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
                out streamids, out warnings);

            string filename = mstrFilePath + "\\" + batch + run + "\\" + PreSortID.ToString(fmt) + ".PDF";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
            Report.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
      }
```

Comment: if it doesn't work, it doesn't fit code review.  have you tested the code you provided?

Comment: Based on how your question was posed, I am under the impression that your code is working, but running out of memory on large cases; I've edited your question to reflect this and have accordingly voted not to close it. *I am not familiar with C#*, so if this is not the case, then your question is unfortunately off-topic and will be closed as such; we review only working code here on Code Review.

Answer (score 10):

I probably can't solve your issue with memory but I will say that you are loading a large `DataSet` into memory from ADO, and then you are not `Dispose`-ing the `DataSet`. This will not release the resources associated with the `DataSet` (it is not guaranteed to Dispose or be GCed after it goes out of scope), which could be a contributing factor.

Also worth noting is that `DataSet` has poorer performance than, say, an `IEnumerable`. I know there is a reason for it but I can't put my finger on it and I don't want to do a disservice to you by explaining the wrong one, but you can look [here for a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896238/datatables-vs-ienumerablet) on the performance between the two.

You could convert your `DataSet` to an `IEnumerable` after retrieving it from SQL using `Cast<T>`. After this you can then invoke LINQ comprehensions and operators on the `IEnumerable`. This will be much faster, and also, will be lazily evaluated - this has the benefit of meaning you can build up a query on the `IEnumerable` and return it from your method, and it will never be iterated until you actually need to access the elements. Rejoice! Less computational power needed and less memory needed.

This also has the added benefit of preventing you from having to quite literally copy from one DataTable into another (which is heavy enough as it is).

And another tip - Don't make this method return a void. Your method is doing too much right now. You should split it up into multiple methods - like such.,

```
// Where StronglyTypedRepresentation is a type that holds all of the fields
// you expect to receive back from the stored procedure 
// uspSelectBatchAddressToSortTableAdapter
ReportViewer GeneratePdf(IEnumerable<StronglyTypedRepresentation> data) {}
IEnumerable<StronglyTypedRepresentation> MapSqlResult(DataSet data) {}
void SavePdf(ReportViewer reportViewer) {}
```

Remember that each method ( / type) should only do one single thing.

So, to summarize:

- Split your methods up into more granular chunks
- Convert your initial data from ADO to an `IEnumerable` using `Cast<T>`. LINQ comprehensions are almost always (citation needed - I only have anecdotal evidence to offer) faster. You can always convert what you need to dispatch to the stored procedure back to a datatable if necessary (if you need to convert everything to a stored procedure, then I would suggest doing this computation on the database side as it is optimized to do batch operations)
- Consider that maybe your files *are* too big - if this is the case, find some way of reading them in chunks or splitting the files up before reading them

Comment: @Dan..Thanks for the response and its pretty informative. You definitely made some valid points and I will try to implement them. Just to be on the same page, which dataset are you talking about here? If you notice my code, I use two. One to get all the records to get the count and also enter a loop. Second dataset is used to bind to the report and this dataset uses a tableadapter and accepts parameters. So at any point of time, this dataset will return just one record.

Comment: The data set I was talking about was the one that you fill with the contents of the adapter. I meant to say that you use `Cast` on the *table* of the data set, not the data set itself. Surely the table has more than 1 record when in your OP you state it has ~20k? :)